# How to remove the onTap border cell effect using SfCalendar

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion, sfcalendar

I'm using [SFCalendar](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/calendar/overview)

I have a calendar with appointments, and I want on `onTap` to select only appointments and not be able to select the cell.

I have done something like that :

```dart
SfCalendar(
  //...
  selectionDecoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.transparent,
    border: Border.all(
      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
      width: 2),
    borderRadius:
      const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
  ),
  controller: _calendarController,
  onTap: (details) {
    if (details.targetElement !=
        CalendarElement.appointment) {
      _calendarController.selectedDate = null;
      return;
    }

    // My selection code here
  },
```

But It seems overly complicated.

Does there is a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

try this way -

```
SfCalendar(
  // ...
  selectionDecoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.transparent,
    border: Border.all(
      color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
      width: 2,
    ),
    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
    shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
  ),
  controller: _calendarController,
  onLongPress: (details) {
    if (details.targetElement == CalendarElement.appointment) {
      // Your selection code here
    }
  },
)
```

By using onLongPress, you ensure that only the appointments can be selected when a long press is detected, which might provide a smoother user experience.